# How to pass a map<double,T> from C++ to R with Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, dictionary, stl, rcpp

looking at Rcpp authors's [paper](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-introduction.pdf), I see on page 6 and 7 that `map<T>` and `map<string,T>` can be passed from C++ to R as long as `T` is "wrappable". I have a `map<double,vector<double> >` that I wouls like to pass to R. I was hoping the `double` keys could be casted to `string` in the `wrap` or something but I understand it is not magic.

Do you have a suggestion that would allow me to output such map without copying the whole map to another `map<string, vector<double>>` (this might well be a C++ question after all)?

Find bellow an example of a `map<double,string>` for reproductible example.

```
cCode <- '
    map<double,string> myMap;
    myMap[10.01] = "A1";
    myMap[14.62] = "B1";
    myMap[16.33] = "C1";

    return wrap(myMap); //this failed
';
mapRet <- cxxfunction(signature(), includes='using namespace std;', plugin="Rcpp", body=cCode)
```

PS: I know about `rcpp-devel` list but my stuff looks like noob question so I do not want to spam.

Comment: PS If you think your question is of low value, then it is spam here or on rcpp-devel. I still think you get better quality answers for Rcpp questions over there. Your loss, not mine.

Comment: spam: not really as noob public coming here might have similar question, probably not on list, but I see you point

Comment: I don't understand what you are afraid. What do you think the list is for if not user questions?  But I have made this points for years so...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't even test for equality on a double (see [the R FAQ 7.31](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f)) so I don't see how you could index a map or hash on a double.

In general, "automatic" conversion happens for implicit forms of `as<>()` and `wrap()` where C++ and R have corresponding types on both sides (ie vectors, lists, ... of double, int, ...) and explicit *where you create your own converters*.  You can still do that for your containers, it just cannot be automatic as we do not deliver magic wands.

*Edit:* Ok, just noodled with this on the train.  You can build it both ways in C++, but you can only (automagically) have it mapped back to R as there is only on possible representation: doubles with string labels. Witness:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
std::map<std::string, double> bar() {
  std::map<std::string, double> s;
  s["quick"]  = 3.14;
  s["brown"] = 2.22;
  s["fox"]    = 1.11;
  return s;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
std::map<double, std::string> foo() {
  std::map<double, std::string> s;
  s[3.14] = "quick";
  s[2.22] = "brown";
  s[1.11] = "fox";
  return s;
}
```

and both functions compile, but only the first is accessible from R / exportable. It even works:

```
R> Rcpp::sourceCpp('/tmp/maptest.cpp')
R> bar()
brown   fox quick 
 2.22  1.11  3.14 
R>
```

Comment: There is no need to test for equality here I am not following... `map<double,T>` make sense in C++ as you can define your `<` and `==` but this you know... so as long as I have the map ready in C++ there is just the conversion to do, it is possible to cast the `double` to string so it would come out as a list of [whatever] with names being "2.34", "5.32" or even "l1" "l2" for that matter I would just be happy not to copy the whole map again

Comment: Agreed, I was wrong on the first point ... but there is still **no native R type to map to**.

Comment: Thanks Dirk, I understand this, so I will create another map and copy the contents of `myMap[.]->second` in the the other map which will have string keys. I was just hoping I could avoid this copy using some STL workaround or some Rcpp code you would provide. PS:
FYI using `cxxfunction` the `map<double,string>` code I provided in my example doesn't compile on my PC (windows 7 and r.2.15.2 and Rcpp_0.10.2), you say yours compile so I'll try using your way of writing Rcpp code

Comment: Last word, I noticed Rcpp gallery and Rcpp examples, I have myself compiled some very basic examples (go from R to C++ than back with basic types, modify stuff, use STL), I think it can be usefull for new users. Not sure you have any use for it, your book coming it will probably deal with it much better, but I can send stuff if you want.

Comment: The [Rcpp Gallery](http://gallery.rcpp.org) is open for user contributions.   As for your nested data structure: _you_ need to supply a `wrap()` functions. See Rcpp-extending and several packages that do; there is an example in the Rcpp Gallery too.

Comment: No he wasn't.  Try [this one instead](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/custom-as-and-wrap-example/).

Comment: This is missing an export for `foo()`; adding an additional `// [[Rcpp::export]]` above the function definition makes `bar()` work.

Comment: Correct, will fix.  Thanks for spotting this.